# How to select a list item and show the details dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, jqtouch

Im using jQTouch to make a mobile version of my website, and i need some help.

Im using html5 storage feature. I have a list of jobs and I want to click on one job, and shows that job information in another div.

This is my code:

```
var uid;
var job_name;

for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {    
var row = results.rows.item(i);

uid  = row['id'];
job_name   = row['job_name'];

$("ul#my_jobs").append('<li class="arrow" id="job_' + uid +'"><a class="fade" href="#prueba">' + job_name + '</a></li>');


$("li#job_" + row['id']).bind('tap', function(){
    $("#job_detail").html(row['id']);
});
}
```

The jobs are listing ok, but when I tap on one of them, always shows the last job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this (without changing your layout too much):

```
var uid, job_name;
for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {    
  var row = results.rows.item(i);
  uid  = row['id'];
  job_name   = row['job_name'];

  $("ul#my_jobs").append('<li class="arrow" id="job_' + uid +'"><a class="fade" href="#prueba">' + job_name + '</a></li>');
  (function(id) {
    $("li#job_" + id).bind('tap', function(){
      $("#job_detail").html(id);
    });
  })(uid)
}
```

JavaScript doesn't have block scope here, so that `row` variable, even though it's inside the `for` loop, is scope to the entire function, and it gets replaced each iteration...and ends up being the last value (which is why you see the last `id` each time).

A slimmed down version taking advantage of this new scope would be:

```
for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {    
  var row = results.rows.item(i);
  (function(uid, job_name) {
    $('<li class="arrow" id="job_' + uid +'"><a class="fade" href="#prueba">' + job_name + '</a></li>').bind('tap', function(){
      $("#job_detail").html(uid);
    }).appendTo("#my_jobs");
  })(row['id'], row['job_name']);
}
```

This declares those other `uid` and `jod_name` variables only where they're needed, and eliminated the extra traversal inside the loop (finding the `<li>` you just created).